# UCDevis mib configuration in windows

Tags: windows, dll, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I am trying to configure UCDEVIS MIB to get cpu information in windows. In Linux system its working fine. but in windows it's not working. Please some one help me .

```
Thanks
```

[UCDEVIS Setup](https://www.tuc.gr/fileadmin/Download_Files/Install_Net-SNMP_in_Windows.pdf)

I want to use following MIBS.

```
OID_CPU_FREE   = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.11.0"
OID_DISK_NAME  = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.3"
OID_DISK_USAGE = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.9"
OID_MEM_TOTAL  = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0"
OID_MEM_FREE   = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0"
OID_MEM_BUFFER = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0"
OID_MEM_CACHED = "1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0"
```

We have followed this link

Comment: What SNMP agent do you use? Windows SNMP services implement some but not this MIB document.

Comment: NET-SNMP I am using

Comment: @LexLi I am waiting for your response

Comment: Net-SNMP stopped their Windows port a few years ago, and I don't think anyone cares.

Comment: @LexLi- Thanks for your support. Please do me a favor. Could you please tell me how can I fetch above information. Can we do this another way